# C# Core HttpClient is not working but RestClient (from RestSharp) works

Tags: httpclient

I have API hosted in IIS . I have two client in OpensHift docker container . One client is using RestSharp RestClient to access the API from Openshift , it works . But 2nd client , which uses HttpClient get always response code 503 Service Uunavailable. Any hint to fix this ?